# quantmod 3d graphics

Tags: r, 3d, quantmod

I am trying to use the code on the [quantmod website for a 3d graph](http://www.quantmod.com/examples/chartSeries3d/).  I followed the instructions and entered the year as 2010 (since 2008 link was not found).  However, when I enter this command at the R prompt:

```
 chartSeries3d0(TR)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in if (on == "years") { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I am relatively new to R, so can anyone help me fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Treasury has re-designed its website since that example was created, so the code is not downloading any data (no matter what year you enter).  Instead of using the `getUSTreasuries` function, you can just pull the data from FRED.

```
library(quantmod)
source("http://www.quantmod.com/examples/chartSeries3d/chartSeries3d.alpha.R")

getSymbols("DGS1MO;DGS3MO;DGS6MO;DGS1;DGS2;DGS3;DGS5;DGS7;DGS10;DGS20;DGS30",
  src="FRED")
TR <- merge(DGS1MO,DGS3MO,DGS6MO,DGS1,DGS2,DGS3,DGS5,
  DGS7,DGS10,DGS20,DGS30, all=FALSE)
colnames(TR) <- c("1mo","3mo","6mo","1yr","2yr","3yr","5yr",
  "7yr","10yr","20yr","30yr")
TR <- na.locf(TR)

chartSeries3d0(TR["2011"])
```